# DRCsim point cloud noise

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I launched an empty world with Atlas and added the terrain and a few boxes.
When viewing in Rviz, a noisy point cloud is presented ([see youtube video](http://youtu.be/dQthQrKWqC4)).
[image: image description]

Questions:
a. Is the noise deliberate?
b. If so, is this the Gaussian noise, what is the variance of the noise, and can the variance be changed?

Thanks,

Oded

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2605/drcsim-point-cloud-noise/) by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please see the [`<noise>` block in the multicamera definition for per-pixel noise added to each MultiSense head camera](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/3deeff82b93e757bfe21d8b83d491c20818617a6/ros/multisense_sl_description/urdf/multisense_sl.urdf?at=default#cl-191).  `stereo_image_proc` does not inject any additional noise.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on 2013-04-30**:
I tried removing the noise by rewriting "0.0" in both cameras and compiling and reinstalling, yet the noise was not removed.

**Comment by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on 2013-04-30**:
I tried removing the noise by rewriting "0.0" in both cameras and compiling and reinstalling, yet the noise was not removed.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-04-30**:
Hi odedy86, different stereo vision algorithms produces have different kinds of errors even if you have an ideal camera.  You can look into literatures on stereo algorithm implementation used here (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereobm) to understand these errors.